# tkinter text widget shows me this :TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, widget

I hope you can help me with this error.
I am making a form which has two text type widgets and is not reading the information correctly.

```
def add_student():
    con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root",password="", database="postulantebd")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("insert into postulantes values(%, %, %, %, %, %, %, %, %, %, %)",(
        nombre_var.get(),
        apellido_var.get(),
        cedula_var.get(),
        fdn_var.get(),
        genero_var.get(),
        telefono_var.get(),
        correo_var.get(),
        estado_civil_var.get(),
        cargo_aspira_var.get(),
        txt_direction.get(),
        description_var.get("1.0",END)
        ))

   con.commit()
    
   con.close()
```

The text areas are

```
description_var = Text(descrip_Frame)
txt_direction=Text(Manage_frame,width=30,height=4,font=("Arial",10,"bold"))
```

The error is:

> txt_direction.get(),
> TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'

I tried with

```
txt_direction.get("1.0",END)
```

but I get an error like this:

> ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 32

I'm really stuck, thanks in advance.

Comment: For `Text` widget, use `get('1.0', 'end-1c')`.  Change all `%` to `%s` in `cur.execute(...)` as well.

Answer (score 1):

For `Text` widget, use `get('1.0', 'end-1c')` (`end-1c` discard the automatically added newline at the end).

Also `%s` is used as placeholders for MySQL, so change all `%` to `%s` in the SQL statement.

```py
    cur.execute("insert into postulantes values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(
        nombre_var.get(),
        apellido_var.get(),
        cedula_var.get(),
        fdn_var.get(),
        genero_var.get(),
        telefono_var.get(),
        correo_var.get(),
        estado_civil_var.get(),
        cargo_aspira_var.get(),
        txt_direction.get("1.0", "end-1c"),
        description_var.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        ))
```